# Why does my UITableView content 'jump up' when trying to scroll up the table?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

The best explanation for this, is in [this video I just made of the issue](https://youtu.be/U_lmpmy_Kg4).

I will try to describe it here though, for those who can't view the video, but i really recommend watching the video as it's far more descriptive.

I have controller with a UITableView, and I've stripped it down to be basically as simple as possible. Upon initial load, 10 pieces of data will be fetched. There is also a UIBarButtonItem to fetch 10 additional pieces of data whenever you want.

Now each cell also has 2 variable height label's. The "title" label which can display up to 2 line. And the "subtitle" label which can display up to 5 lines. [NOTE: If I put the same text into every title and the same text into every subtitle, therefore never changing the size of those labels... this issue I'm going to describe is not an issue. Hence why in the video I say I think it has something to do with self sizing cells].

Now, here is the problem: On initial load we get 10 cells. A, B, C..., I, J. I scroll down to J. Then I press the button to fetch 10 more. I now have cells A->T (20 cells). And I'm currently viewing cell J still. The issue is... if I try to scroll up between cell J and cell A... the content will jump. Cells K through T are all fine, and you can scroll up and down on them infinite time. However, if I scroll from J, I, H, G, F... each one will "jump". By jump I mean... my finger is moving down, the content is moving down, and every 100 pixels or so, the content will jump back up 80 pixels. (I really recommend the video, it's way better than the description I'm giving right now). Now if we are at cell F, I can freely scroll down and back to through cell's F -> T. J, I, H, G, F will no longer jump as they've already 'jumped' once. However, if I scroll up to E, D, C, B, A... which I've haven't scrolled to yet... each one's content will 'jump' up a bit while scrolling up to them.

**tl;dr:** A UITableView has 0..N rows. X is a value between 0..N inclusively. The user can fetch additional rows Y, which will make the new TableView count 0..(N+Y). The issue is... on initial load, the user can scroll to row X. Then fetch Y additional rows. Then, scrolling up to rows 0..(X-1) will have a 'content jumping' issue, where as the users finger moves down on the device to scroll the content down, the content will 'jump' back up 50 pixels with every displayed cell between 0..(X-1). Cell's X..(N+Y) do not have this issue. Once a cell has gone through this 'jumping content' issue, it will not go through again, unless another fetch is done.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have the exact same issue here. I was wondering if you found the solution to this? It seems like the problem happens everytime after tableview is reloaded. Thanks

Comment: @EdwardHung oh wow. This was so long ago I don't remember. But I do know I fixed it. I'm sure it had something to do with the automatic dimension or whatever it's called for self sizing cells. Actually no wait. I think it had to do with the default size you give it. So for example you may have cells that are 100 to 300 in height. So perhaps you set its default size to around 200. It had something to do with that default size. I feel like I remember changing the default value of the cell size and the distance of the jumping completely changed.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you scroll your tableview the cellforrowatindexpath method is being called and a new cell is being created.

So if you are simultaneously making a data call there will be noticeable lag in the tableview.

Here is an example method for calling something on a background thread.`-

(IBAction)backgroundQueue:(id)sender {

```
// call the same method on a background thread
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];
    int i = arc4random() % 100;

    // update UI on the main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.title = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Result: %d", i];
    });

});
```

}`

Try putting your data call method on the background thread which allow the main thread to be used for UI updates.

Comment: I've got all my webclient calls on a backgroud thread. Originally I had implemented an "infinite scrolling" where you scroll down to the bottom of the tableView, spin a UIActivityIndicator, and then fetch more data from the server. I decided to take that out temporarily, and make an additional fetch call after an arbitrary 5 seconds. The scrolling issue though has nothing do to with the fetch. The fetch is asynch, and loaded into my NSMutableArray object when I'm scrolling. I'm dong the scrolling well after all of this has completed.